# Renaming arrays in excel vba when looping

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am currently downloading price history of stocks from yahoo finance.   I have a For next loop that goes through a list of ticker symbols of stocks and then retrieves that data from yahoo Finance.

Right now I have 380 different stocks that I up load into excel without six years of price history for each stock. I want to get all of this data off my excel sheet and into vba arrays.

I can get vba to populate one array, but, I cannot figure out how to do two things-

1.) I want the array name to be variable, meaning when my for next loop is running and getting data off the web; I want the array name to be the current ticker symbol in the loop.

2.) After the array is named with the current ticker symbol, then I want to be able to save the array and continue on with my loop. When the loop cycles again I want a new array to be named with the new ticker symbol, and then saved with the last array.

```
  Option Explicit

    Sub Macro4()



    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ticker As String, sday, smonth, syear, eday, emonth, eyear As Long
    Dim arrayDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim currentArray As Variant
    Dim x As Long


    For x = 6 To 10


    ticker = Cells(x, 2)
    sday = Day(Cells(5, 6))
    smonth = Month(Cells(5, 6)) - 1
    syear = Year(Cells(5, 6))
    eday = Day(Cells(5, 9))
    emonth = Month(Cells(5, 9)) - 1
    eyear = Year(Cells(5, 9))

     Range("f6", "k1000000").ClearContents

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & ticker & "&d=" &  emonth & "&e=" & eyear & "&f=" & eyear & "&g=d&a=" & smonth & "&b=" & sday & "&c=" & syear & "&ignore=.csv" _
        , Destination:=Cells(6, 6))
        .Name = "table.csv?s=UGAZ&d=4&e=7&f=2016&g=d&a=1&b=8&c=2012&ignore="
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With


        currentArray = Range("n7", Range("n6").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
        arrayDict.Add ticker, currentArray

    Next x

    For x = 6 to 10

        ticker = Cells(x, 2)
        currentArray = arrayDict(ticker)

   Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Everything worked when I was watching the locals window until the loop was complete then all the arrays are gone I have no Idea where they went?? after the first loop is when there are problems

Comment: I think the closest thing to variables with names that you choose at runtime are dictionaries, have a look into that. If you don't care about the actual names, maybe a multidimensional array would be enough.

Comment: The name of the array is very important because I have well over a 1000 of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that dictionaries best suit your needs

like in this pseudo code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim arrayDict As New Scripting.Dictionary '<--| needs reference to "Microsft Scripting Runtime" library
    Dim currentArr As Variant '<--| this will hold your current array, both when storing into a dictionary item and when retrieving from dictionary
    Dim tickerSymbol As String '<--| this will hol your current "ticker symbol"

    Dim i As Long

    For ... '<--| your loop
        tickerSymbol = ... '<--| your code to define the ticker symbol
        currentArr = ... '<--| your code to define the current array attached to the ticker symbol
        arrayDict.Add tickerSymbol, currentArr
    Next 

    tickerSymbol=...'<--|chose a ticker symbol
    currentArr = arrayDict(tickerSymbol) '<--| retrieve its corresponding array from the dictionary

End Sub
```

Comment: I am new to this site and I finally got the code to post right, I appreciate both of your answers, I have been studying dictionaries all afternoon on youtube, and I have tried your current code, but I was unsuccessful. I hope now that I have posted my code that maybe you could fine tune it for me

Comment: Take my pseudocode and insert your code where it is asked to. Keep that "Option Explicit" at the very top to force you declare all your variables. Then get to the point where you can compile it. To this end you also have to add your project the reference to "Microsft Scripting Runtime" library. Then try and run it to see what happens and get back to your code to amend it from offending code. If you need help post the entire (compiling) code and point out where it errors out (which line) with error details (error number and message).

Comment: It works in the first loop as far as populating but after the loop is complete and the sub has ended all of the arrays are gone.

Comment: if you need some variables _survive_ the sub they are initialized in, then either you pass those variables as arguments to the sub or you make those variables `Public`. I'd highly recommend the former.

Comment: How do you make a variable public? The info on the Q and A is not very clear

Comment: really? declare them with the format `Public variablename As variableType` instead of `Dim variablename As variableType`. BTW if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: @ZacAttack, did you get through it?

Comment: I still have not figured it out but I am busy during the week with work so only have limited time.